# Azure SQL Authentication connection string in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

Microsoft allows use of the Authentication command in Azure SQL to connect to the database using an Azure AD account.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/

Under heading ***7.1. Connecting using integrated (Windows) authentication***

How can I use this on an Azure App Service?

Note: I am specifically trying *NOT* to include the password as the next heading shows.  I specifically want integrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of the documentation is correct, you can achieve this yourself using Token Based authentication. It shouldn't require anything special from Azure App Service. See here for details and sample code:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/02/09/token-based-authentication-support-for-azure-sql-db-using-azure-ad-auth/

> The new token-based authentication method allows middle-tier services to obtain a token from Azure AD and use it to connect to Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Sounds like what I wanted does not yet exist.  I will try this as an alternative.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service machines are not part of your domain, so this isn't going to work. This was designed to let domain joined clients connect to SQL.

SQL Username/password is the only option left.

Update: see Chris Post about the new token based features

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. Per the documentation, middle tier applications are able to connect to a SQL Azure database using token authentication. You might be confusing the domain-join requirement for using SQL Server Management Studio to connect using AAD credentials.

Comment: @ChrisGillum, You are right, according to the newly released feature you mention. Didn't know that yet (and wasn't it the link of the question)